# Erro dizendo que a Activity não foi declarada no Androidmanifest.xlm?

Tags: android

Este é o código do meu Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activitys.mainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activitys.loginActivity" />
</application>
```

E este é o erro:

> Error running 'app': The activity 'loginActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Img:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara só uma dica, nome de pacotes são sempre minúsculos, e nomes de classes sempre começão com a primeira letra maiúscula

Answer (score 1):

O que pode acontecer é que está com mais um arquivo `loginActivity` ou ele não existe nesse diretório.

Para ter certeza de que existe ou de qual você está apontando, especifique o caminho completo da `Activity` para descobrir se realmente está correto.

Você pode declarar desta forma:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.Activitys.loginActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```